# Creating a view of unused videos in a month period in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Hello again to the community.

This time I'm trying to create a view of all the videos that have not been loaned in the month. The table has this structure:

| transaction | c_id | v_id | loan_date | return_loan | rental_value | period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-08-12 | 10.00 | 2021-08 |

and it keeps on being populated...

So I'm generating a view using the following code:

```
CREATE VIEW `Video not rented` AS 
SELECT  loan.period, loan.v_id, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM loan 
WHERE amount = 0
GROUP BY loan.v_id;
```

But I get the following error:

> 0 146 13:29:13 Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function    0.000 sec

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question is unclear.  It looks like your need a having clause as noted previously, but the field "amount" is not listed in the structure in your post.

Answer (score 1):

This owulf show you all perod for a video that wasn't lent out

```
CREATE VIEW `Video not rented` AS 
SELECT  loan.period, loan.v_id, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM loan 
GROUP BY loan.v_id,loan.period
HAVING  amount = 0;
```

you can use to get the last period

```
CREATE VIEW `Video not rented` AS 
SELECT  MAX(loan.period), loan.v_id, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM loan 
GROUP BY loan.v_id
HAVING  amount = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join`.  Assuming you have a table of videos:

```
CREATE VIEW videos_not_rented_this_month
    SELECT v.*
    FROM videos v LEFT JOIN
         loan l
         ON l.v_id = v.v_id AND
            l.loan_date >= curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate())) day
    WHERE l.v_id IS NULL;   -- videos with no match
```

Comment: I do have a videos table too. I'll give it a try to see how it works

Comment: seems the syntax is throwing an error because curdate() + is expecting a 1 to see which format i want to see curdate() in. curdate() = YYYY-MM-DD / curdate() + 1 = YYYYMMDD

Comment: @JuanPabloClavijo . . . I fixed the typo (a missing closing paren).